# Disable regular expression parsing in curl

Tags: regex, bash, api, curl

I am trying to curl an API that accepts a regular expression as one of the arguments.

I discovered that curl is trying to be smart here and is parsing the regular expression itself, rather than treating it as part of the URL. So every time I launch the curl command, it then proceeds to make 70,000 HTTP requests. It should only be making one.

Example: `https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123[4-5][6-7][8-9])`

In this case, I want the literal HTTP request to be, well, *that*.

Instead, I get:

```
[1/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123468) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123468)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[2/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123469) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123469)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[3/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123478) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123478)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[4/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123479) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123479)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[5/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123568) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123568)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[6/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123569) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123569)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[7/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123578) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123578)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com

[8/8]: https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123579) --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123579)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.example.com
```

How can I disable this regex parsing that curl has?

I checked `curl --help all` and there is nothing there about this kind of parsing. I also checked the man page for curl. There is nothing there, either; this seems to be a completely undocumented "helpful" feature.

It does seem to be curl, not the shell, because this does not seem to happen with wget, which makes only one (failing request).

Trying to escape the brackets with `\` seems to prevent the parsing, but also transforms the characters in a way which doesn't look right:

```
root@voip:/tmp# wget "https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123\[4-5\]\[6-7\]\[8-9\])"
--2021-11-05 11:26:03--  https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123%5C[4-5%5C]%5C[6-7%5C]%5C[8-9%5C])
Resolving api.example.com (api.example.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘api.example.com’
root@voip:/tmp# wget "https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123\[4-5]\[6-7]\[8-9])"
--2021-11-05 11:26:25--  https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123%5C[4-5]%5C[6-7]%5C[8-9])
Resolving api.example.com (api.example.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘api.example.com’
```

Comment: You need to URI encode your regex so that you're producing a valid URL. You should also surround your URL in single or double quotes; I forget which one Bash requires.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm using double quotes, it doesn't even work without them

Comment: Okay, and the URI encode? My quotes comment was based on your initial edit which made it impossible to know whether you're issuing the command properly.

Comment: The usual URL encoder I'm using produces this, which doesn't look right, either:  "https%3A%2F%2Fapi.example.com%2Fv1%2F%3Fregex%3D%28123%5B4-5%5D%5B6-7%5D%5B8-9%5D%29". Should the // in the URL turn into this? Or this encoder doing the wrong thing?

Comment: The encoder is right. Per my previous comment, you should only apply it to the regex. `?regex=URI_ENCODED_STRING`

Comment: Try `curl 'https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123[4-5][6-7][8-9])'` with single quotes or `curl "https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=(123[4-5][6-7][8-9])"` with double quotes and perhaps url-encode your variable value: `curl "https://api.example.com/v1/?regex=%28123[4-5][6-7][8-9]%29"` The chars ( [ ? have special meaning in bash and need to be protected by quoting or escaping (a.k.a. backslashing in bash).

Comment: Quotes only protect against the shell itself. In Bash, single quotes are the stronger form of quoting; the shell will not touch anything (even backslashes) between single quotes - but of course this does noting to prevent `curl` from processing wildcard expressions in the quoted string (`curl` can't even know whether you quoted it or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable URL sequences and ranges using {} and [], you can use option `-g`.